# Javascript: Checking if string contains a character, then removing part of a string?

Tags: javascript, string, character, contains, intervals

Essentially what this function is supposed to do is take a list of words from input text and set it on a display at a client-chosen interval (WPM) from a drop-down menu.

If a word passed in the function contains a question mark, period, colon, semi-colon, exclamation point or comma, then it is removed, and the chosen interval is doubled. For example, if the delay between words was 117 ms, it would then be 234 ms.

I'm having the most trouble working out the part where you determine whether or not the passed word contains punctuation and removing it.

I'm getting an error: 
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

I'm not sure why this is happening since `list[index++]` is a `String` and `indexOf` is a method of Strings in Javascript and not a property.

I'm also not sure how I would implement the delay. Given that I've used `setInterval()` in this way (and I can only use setInterval for the purposes of this) I'm not sure how I would get it to set the `String` in the display twice while also including the delay.

```
function runDisplay(data, id) {
        var reader = document.getElementById(id);
        var index = 0;
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        if (data.length) {
            timer = setInterval(function() {


            var punctuation = [".", ",", ":", ";", "!", "?"];
            var textSpeed = 117; // default
            for (var j = 0; j < punctuation.length; j++) {
                // remove punctuation if found and double text delay
                // if multiple found, remove only one
                if (!(data[index++].indexOf(punctuation[j]) === -1)) {
                    data[index++] = string.replace(punctuation[j], '');
                // set data[index++] to display twice to double delay?
                }
            } 



            reader.innerHTML = data[index++];
            index = index % data.length;
          }, textSpeed);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting an error: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property
>   'indexOf' of undefined.
>
> I'm not sure why this is happening since list[index++] is a String and
>   indexOf is a method of Strings in Javascript and not a property.

First, methods are also properties of objects.

Second, the JS engine is telling you that you're calling `indexOf` on something `undefined`, so it's not a string. And `data[index++]` is undefined because `index` is probably not an index inside the range of the `data`array.

The main problem of the function is that if `data` is a word array, you don't iterate correctly on it. Here you're incrementing `index`each time you're reading the array, `index` should be incremented only once for each display.

> I'm also not sure how I would implement the delay. Given that I've
>   used setInterval() in this way (and I can only use setInterval for the
>   purposes of this) I'm not sure how I would get it to set the String in
>   the display twice while also including the delay.

If the function has to display all the words in a infinite loop (that's the purpose of `index = index % data.length`, right ?), clearInterval and another setInterval could be called inside the anonymous function passed to the current setInterval, allowing to compute the textSpeed you want.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out how to approach the issues with my program.

Answer (score 1):

`index++` will increase index variable every time it is called and you are calling it twice in your loop body.
In `if (!(data[index++].indexOf(punctuation[j]) === -1)) {`index is lets say i and in `data[index++] = string.replace(punctuation[j], '');` it's i+1.

Answer (score 1):

The code is messy but I hope that's what you wanted ...kind of:

```
var str = "some text with no punctuation. And some;: text. with, punctuation? symbols!!? to print"

var print = function(str) {
    var re = /([^ .,:;!?]+)|([.,:;!?]+)/gi
    var reSkip = /[.,:;!?]+/gi           //remove + to add delay for each punctuation symbol instead of the group of symbols
    var substrs = str.match(re)

    var delay = 117
    var timeToPrint = new Date().getTime() + delay
    var i = 0

    console.log(substrs.length)
    var printWord = function() {
        console.log(substrs[i])
        if ( new Date().getTime() < timeToPrint ) {
            console.log(new Date().getTime() +'<'+timeToPrint)
            requestAnimationFrame(printWord)
            return
        }
        if ( reSkip.test(substrs[i]) ) {
            i++
            timeToPrint += delay*5              //to make delay more obvious
            console.log('skip punctuation')
            requestAnimationFrame(printWord)
            return
        }
        document.write(substrs[i++] + ' ')     //replace this with your code to print where you want
        timeToPrint += delay
        console.log('written')
        if (i < substrs.length)
            requestAnimationFrame(printWord)
    }
    printWord()
}
print(str)
```

Just paste it to chrome console to test.